# In C++, are using reference types for member fields considered proper usage? Particularly when memory is allocated and owned outside the class

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

When memory is allocated and owned outside a class, is it cool to use a reference member field to reference the memory rather than passing it through as a pointer?

I'm mostly looking for best practices and what is and isn't "proper" usage.

There can't be any smart pointers.

Something like:

```
struct Fizz
{
    std::vector<bool> m_results;
    bool m_finalResult;
};

class Bar
{
public:
    Bar(Fizz& _givenFizz)
        : m_heldFizz(_givenFizz)
    {
    }

    void StartRunningThingsAsync()
    {
        // Run calculations with m_heldFizz.m_results asyncronously and then
        //    return from the other thread using the signal
        {
            m_heldFizz.m_finalResult = m_heldFizz.m_results[0];
            emit SignalStuffIsDone();
        }
    }

Q_SIGNALS:
    void SignalStuffIsDone();

private:
    Fizz& m_heldFizz;
};

class Foo
{
public:
    void RunCalculations()
    {
        m_usedFizz = new Fizz();
        m_usedFizz->m_results = {true, false};

        m_usedBar = new Bar(*m_usedFizz);
        connect(m_usedBar, &Bar::SignalStuffIsDone, this, &Foo::OnSignalStuffIsDone);
        m_usedBar->StartRunningThingsAsync();
    }

public Q_SLOTS:
    void OnSignalStuffIsDone()
    {
        if ( m_usedFizz->m_finalResult )
        {
            // Do some stuff
            std::cout << "Result is True";
        }
        else
        {
            // Do some different stuff
            std::cout << "Result is False";
        }

        delete m_usedBar;
        delete m_usedFizz;
    }

private:
    Fizz* m_usedFizz;
    Bar* m_usedBar;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Foo foo1 = Foo();
    foo1.RunCalculations();
    std::cout << "Done";
}
```

I'm not sure if that's something that's ok over vs having Bar be something more like:

```
class Bar
{
public:
    Bar(Fizz* _givenFizz)
        : m_heldFizz(_givenFizz)
    {
    }

    void StartRunningThingsAsync()
    {
        // Run calculations with m_heldFizz.m_results asyncronously and then
        //    return from the other thread using the signal
        {
            m_heldFizz.m_finalResult = m_heldFizz.m_results[0];
            emit SignalStuffIsDone();
        }
    }

Q_SIGNALS:
    void SignalStuffIsDone();

private:
    Fizz* m_heldFizz;
};
```

Comment: "There can't be any smart pointers." why not ?

Comment: Using a reference as a class member has the same impact as using a const ptr. Both delete the default copy assignment operator. Fine so long as you don't need it or are willing to write a replacement which is only meaningfully doable in c++20. A ptr, unlike a reference doesn't have to be const and doesn't delete the assignment operator.

Comment: you can use whichever one you want. I tend to prefer pointers but my boss does not.

Comment: it is "proper" and "ok" but I would not use a reference member unless I have too. References are nicer than pointers in general, but not so much as members

Comment: No smart pointers because my workplace doesn't allow them.

Comment: What about them being members are you not a fan of @463035818_is_not_a_number

Comment: @JCroArr what doug said. And compared to smart pointers you have no way to know if the object is still alive. Why do you rule out smart pointers?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number my workplace doesn't allow them to be used, so they're not an option.

Comment: In the case where the calculations are being run asynchronously on another thread, does being able to check if they're alive help? Couldn't something delete it between when the check is made and when the memory is written to?

Comment: Imho you should be preferring references, if possible, since they indicate something cannot be null. There are scenarios where you simply cannot use references though... However even if the member variable is a pointer, since e.g. you need a copyable/movable class, your constructor should still have a reference parameter instead of a pointer parameter to clearly indicate to the caller that null is not a valid input...

Comment: Note that you can always use reference_wrapper.